# Deployment to JBoss EAP 7 with Maven Wildfly plugin

Tags: maven, jboss, wildfly, jboss-eap-7

I'm trying to deploy an application to a local JBoss EAP 7.0 server through Maven. The deploy works fine through both the management console and manually deploying through the "doDeploy" method.

I'm not sure what i need to do in order to get it working.

I've tried following the instructions found on the website but to no avail: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/configuration_guide/deploying_applications#deploying_apps_using_maven

here is the relevant part of the pom.xml

```
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}_${project.version}</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <doclint>none</doclint>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1.Final</version>
            <configuration>
                <hostname>${deploy.jboss.hostname}</hostname>
                <username>${deploy.jboss.user}</username>
                <password>${deploy.jboss.pass}</password>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

I'm unfortunately getting the following error from maven when running `mvn clean wildfly:deploy -X -e`

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYCTL0216: Management resource '[]' not found
at org.wildfly.plugin.core.DefaultDeploymentManager.hasDeployment(DefaultDeploymentManager.java:370)
at org.wildfly.plugin.core.DefaultDeploymentManager.hasDeployment(DefaultDeploymentManager.java:331)
at org.wildfly.plugin.core.DefaultDeploymentManager.forceDeploy(DefaultDeploymentManager.java:85)
at org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.DeployMojo.executeDeployment(DeployMojo.java:70)
at org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.AbstractDeployment.execute(AbstractDeployment.java:150)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
... 21 more
```

Any ideas as to what could be causing the problem?

EDIT: I've made some progress in identifying the issue. The issue seems to stem from my standalone.xml server configuration used rbac authentication mechanism. Using "simple" the deployment works immediately but using "rbac" with a specific username and password it fails and i cannot get it working. I've opened a ticket on the JBoss forums here to further exposure: https://developer.jboss.org/message/980860#980860

Comment: That error looks very strange. Are you running in standalone mode?

Comment: Hi James. Yeah that's correct, it's in standalone mode. i'll add more detail to the original ticket in a sec as i've made some progress in identifying a route cause.

Comment: Thanks. I'll see if I can reproduce it locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who runs into this problem, the issue was that by changing the standalone.xml to use "rbac" manually, it does not 'fully' disable the simple authentication. After some discovery by James R. Perkins he identified the issue but it can be manually resolved by doing the following to the standalone.xml:

```
<management>  
    <security-realms>  
        <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">  
            <authentication>  
                <local default-user="$local" skip-group-loading="true"/> <!-- THIS LINE WAS REMOVED -->
```

The final line was removed and i was now able to deploy using the maven plugin.

For more detailed info, see the question posted on the JBoss developer forums here: https://developer.jboss.org/message/980860#980860